# Is object oriented programming considered to be a declarative programming approach?

Tags: object-oriented, programming-paradigms, imperative-programming

Is object oriented programming considered to be a declarative programming approach?

On Wikipedia, it is said that OOP tries to extend the imperative programming paradigm to a somewhat declarative programming approach, but **what precisely makes OOP imperative or declarative?**

Comment: The distinction between imperative and declarative has always been a matter of degree based on a context of comparison, and somewhat a wooly distinction even then in my opinion. I would treat the term as effectively meaningless in the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

**When you write an OO code, you describe object features** (attributes, properties, methods) and implement them. This may be seen as declarative: you do not have an imperative approach giving the sequence of operations to reach a given goal; you have a declarative approach *describing* features of objects, in a sense characterizing them.

To be more precise, let me take an example. When one says that an image has a filtered version, a blurred version, etc, this may be seen as declarative; these are features of any image. When one implements a procedure to filter or blur an image, then this is imperative: the code is thought of as a sequence of operations aiming at transforming an image, not a description of what the transformed image is.

I am not an expert, though, so I hope someone will correct this if needed.

Comment: Yes, I don't think this approach would bear much weight. Certainly, OO code is still concerned with explicitly sequencing operations. Member methods are written imperatively, and if the resulting method when taken as a whole (that is, when reduced to its descriptive name, and the implementation innards treated as a black box or subject to change) is considered "declarative", then so is every subroutine in any language.